# How to execute query in Odoo-8 from Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

I have the following function in the class `hr_evaluation_interview`:

```
@api.onchange('evaluation_id')
def onchange_evalID(self):
    self.deadline=self.env.cr.execute('SELECT date FROM hr_evaluation_evaluation where id=119')
```

Note: I'm just giving `id=119` in the query for testing purposes.

When I give `self.deadline=datetime.now.strftime(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` it works fine and changes the value of field `deadline` when the value of field `evaluation_id` changes. Again for just testing.

What I really need is to execute a query similar to what I mentioned. However when I execute this query nothing is printing on the `deadline` field. When I check the log I see this warning:

```
WARNING db_name openerp.models: Cannot execute name_search, no _rec_name defined on hr_evaluation.evaluation
```

I tried checking online why this warning, but got no help. Am I doing something wrong? How exactly can I execute query from within `@api.onchange(self)`?

Comment: There are many such examples already available in core code of odoo for executing the query. Here after executing the query, you still need to call the fetch statement, to get the result.

Comment: could you please provide some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Hardik said, `cr.execute()` doesn't return directly you result. You need to fetch the values from the cursor after executing the query. Try like this:

```
@api.onchange('evaluation_id')
def onchange_evalID(self):
    self.env.cr.execute('SELECT date '
                               'FROM hr_evaluation_evaluation where id=119')
    self.deadline = self.env.cr.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'`  :/ Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I tried this query with Postgres separately and it works fine so the return is not None for this query.

Comment: The database I'm trying to fetch data from is defined in another model class (hr_evaluation_interview) and I'm working in another model class in the same file (hr_evaluation_interview). But when executing the query, it doesn't matter from which model I'm executing right?

Answer (score 1):

If `evaluation_id` is `m2o` field of `hr.evaluation.evaluation` model you can try below code. you don't need to execute query at all.

```
@api.onchange('evaluation_id')
def onchange_evalID(self):
    if self.evaluation_id and self.evaluation_id.date:
        self.date = self.evaluation_id.date
```